# How can one create multiple distinct publication collections categorized by tags in the Hugo Academic CV Theme?

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I'm using the Hugo Academic CV Theme, available for download from its [Github page](https://github.com/HugoBlox/theme-academic-cv) or directly through [this link](https://github.com/HugoBlox/theme-academic-cv/archive/refs/heads/main.zip).

Question: How can I organize my publications into distinct collections based on specific tags assigned to their markdown files, ensuring that each publication only appears within its designated collection?

In the `content` folder, I modified the `_index.md` file to add a new collection named 'Other Publications' with a filter tag 'Other' (as shown in the image below). Additionally, I attempted to ensure that this new collection page appears at the URL `./other-publications/`.

[image: _index.md under the content folder]

Subsequently, within the `content/publication/journal-article` directory, I edited the markdown file for the example publication, `index.md`, by incorporating a tag with the value 'Other' (refer to the image below).

[image: index.md in the folder content/publication/journal-article]

However, this doesn't function as intended, as evidenced in the images below: no publications are shown in the new collection, and clicking the link "... filtering publications" leads to a "404 Page not found" error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: no publications shown in the new collection]

[image: ./other-publications/ does not work]